# How to express the order of running program?

Tags: usage

> 1. Start program B after program A is **over**.
> 2. Start program B after program A **finished**.

Which one or other not mentioned here is the best way to express my meaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We would normally say,  "Start program B after program A has finished" or "... A is finished".

You could also say "has completed" or "is completed".